# Percent Symbol in CodeIgniter URI

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I need to pass an encoded string to a CodeIgniter controller.

**Example**:

```
DOSOMETHING/Coldplay/Fix+You/273/X+%26+Y/
```

My problem is the percent symbol that is a disallowed character. I've tried to change the config file with the following:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\+\%';
```

The `+` is ok, but the `%` is not valid. Can you help me to change this reg exp so it will allow the `%` symbol? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put the "**-**" at the end of the string otherwise it gets interpreted as range. The % is already in the allowed character list as you can see.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+-';
```

---

Ahem... after looking at your sample string again. Here is why you get "`The URI you submitted has disallowed characters`".

**Short explanation**: Add the ampersand **&** to the allowed characters list

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+&-';
```

---

**Long explanation**

There are 2 things playing together.

**A)** CodeIgniter checks all URI **segments** for disallowed characters. This happens by whitelisting allowed characters. Which ones are allowed can be checked in /*system/application/config/config.php* in the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` variable. The default value is set to something like `'a-z 0-9~%.:_-'`. Thus all letters from a to z, space, all numbers and the following characters *~%.:_- are allowed.

Ok let us compare that to your sample URI which you say works

```
a-z 0-9~%.:_-
DO_SOMETHING/Coldplay/Fix+You/273/X+26+Y/   //note the missing %
```

All characters are ok... but wait what about the plus sign **+**? It's not in the list of allowed characters! And yet the URI is not complained about? This is the key to your problem.

**B)** CodeIgniter [urldecodes](http://www.php.net/urldecode) the URI segments prior to the whitelist-character-check to prevent that someone circumvents the check by simply urlencoding the URI. Thus the **+** gets decoded to a space. This behaviour is because of [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) (which encodes spaces as **+** sign, deviating from [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)). That explains why the **+** sign is allowed.

These two things combined explain also why this specific URI doesn't work.

```
urldecode(DO_SOMETHING/Coldplay/Fix+You/273/X+%26+Y/) //evaluates to
//DO_SOMETHING/Coldplay/Fix You/273/X & Y/
```

Whoops... the urldecoding translates **%26** to an **&**

Which isn't an allowed character. Mistery ;-) solved

Comment: Thanks for the input but this doesn't solve my problem :(
I still get The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I changed the line as you sugested and it works ok but when I enter a % in the url it breaks.

The example I try is the same:
DO_SOMETHING/Coldplay/Fix+You/273/X+%26+Y/

If I delete the % works perfect...

Comment: Enhanced answer. Overlooked the problem specific to your URI the first time

Comment: :) God damn URLDECODE, I have looked at the code in URI.php but the xss clean is doing the job so I missed it.

Thank you now everything is perfect.

Comment: jitter that's a -great- answer. Good elaboration and research, thanks for putting time into it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";