# Allowing any character in the URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, security, url

I'm using the CodeIgniter PHP framework. I use JS to dynamically load a PHP page:

```
$('someIFrame').writeAttribute(
   'src',
   '/index.php/controller/method/' +
   escape(userGeneratedString)
);
```

When I ran this, CodeIgniter gave me this error:

```
http://192.168.0.81/index.php/controller/method/dude%27s%20face
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

This is totally untrue because the URL in question did not contain any disallowed characters. My config file allows all the characters present in that URL:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@\-';
```

So I got frustrated and just allowed all characters to prevent the error.

```
// Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
// DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
//$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@\-';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

The warning message above this line sounds scary. What can possibly go wrong by allowing all characters? Will I get hacked?

Comment: See also on [security.se]: [**Why is it dangerous to allow all characters in a URL?**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/133511/12139)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The urls in codeigniter are [urldecoded](http://www.php.net/urldecode), so `%27` translates to `'` which wasn't on your allowed character list and therefore triggered the error. So you need to allow the characters **once decoded**.
In other words, by the time codeigniter sees you `%27`, it's already decoded into a `'`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021609/percent-symbol-in-codeigniter-uri)