# Codeigniter & jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I can not insert the data by forms in the database with ajax,There is no firebug error someone can help me

View:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Blog</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
 <h3 style="text-align: center;">CODEIGNITER AJAX</h3>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="message" style="display: none;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <?php echo form_open('blog_c',array('id'=>'myForm'));?>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>EMAIL:</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="ENVOYER" id="btn">
   <?php echo form_close()?>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#btn').click(function(){
    var email=$('#email').val();
    $.ajax({              //request ajax
     url:"<?php echo site_url('blog_c/registre')?>",
     type:POST,
     data:{email:email},
     dataType:json,
      success: function(repons) {
                      $("#message").html(repons);
                     
                   },
                  error: function() {
                     alert("Invalide!");
                  }
    });
   });
  });
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog_m extends CI_Model
{
 function __construct()
  {
     parent:: __construct();
   }
  function registre($data)
 {
  $this->db->insert('utilisateurs',$data);
 } 

}
```

Controler:

```html
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog_c extends CI_Controller 
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  
 }

 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('blog_w');
 }

 public function registre()
 {
  // set rules
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','EMAIL','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[utilisateurs.email]');
 if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
  {
   echo validation_errors();
  }else{
   $data=array(
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'));
   $this->blog_m->registre($data);
   

   echo "<div class='alert'>Inscription success</div>";
   echo "email";
  }
 }

}
```

There is no error but the data does not insert in the database and there is no success message.

Comment: Have you inspected the request to check if the correct form data is being sent, and what headers are being received?

Comment: You're probably getting a PHP error into the error log, and Codeigniter or php.ini might be configured to not display php errors, since otherwise the echoed html, whether it's a validation error or a success, would be picked by jQuery and displayed in the message div

Comment: samiles, I received ok 200ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

**In View *(AJAX Part)***

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#btn" ).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var email= $("#email").val();

            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/blog_c/registre",
                    data:{ email:email},
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#message").html(response);
                        $('#cartmessage').show();
                    }
                    error: function() 
                    {
                        alert("Invalide!");
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**In Controller**

```
public function registre()
{

    $email = $this->input->post('email'); # add this

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','EMAIL','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[utilisateurs.email]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {               
        if(!$this->blog_m->registre($email))
        {
            echo "Something Went Wrong";
        }               
        else
        {
            echo "Inscription success";
        }

    }
}
```

---

**In Model**

```
function registre($email)
{
    $data = array(
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
            );

    $this->db->insert('utilisateurs',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller load model first.Like this..

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));//loads required heplers
        $this->load->model('blog_m');//loads your model 
    }
```

In view: you are using ajax so set form `action` empty.Like this..

```
<?php echo form_open('',array('id'=>'myForm'));?>
```

Comment: and there is no problem about encode json,in you opinion