# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters error on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem. I am using the uri->segment() method of codeigniter to catch a get variable with this string value:

"Introducción e Interpretación Norma ISO 9001:2008"

It's in spanish and when I send it via the url I get the error:

"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

if I remove the ":" from the string, it doesn't give me the error.

This is what my config.php file has:

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';

Can anyone help me detect the source of this error? Thanks.

Comment: This may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170418/allowing-any-character-in-the-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: It's the `ó` that's causing the problem. Allow it in your permitted chars.

Comment: hi alisa, I wasn't able to solve the problem.

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1021690/1004319

Comment: The problem seems to be related with a space character before the numbers. But it's still difficult to detect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `/system/application/config/config.php` file, set this variable as

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=';
```