# codeigniter allowed characters in url

Tags: url, codeigniter-2

Using codeigniter I have a problems to pass variables in my back end like

```
http://localhost:4949/admin/delete_post/6/?action=delete
```

producing `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

I know that this problem could be corrected from config.php `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, but how could I exclude from filtering my backend and to permit this kind of structure and leave the frontend intact.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this with an ampersand (&)

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+&-';
```

It may solve your problem.

Detailed Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021609/percent-symbol-in-codeigniter-uri)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of formatting is not necessary in Codeigniter.  Although query strings can be enabled, using them in my opinion goes against codeigniters way of handeling things. As you can pass variables from your views via uri.

```
http://yourdomain_baseurl/controller/controller_function/var1/var2/var3
```

I suggest doing the following:

Send variables in an url like this:

```
http://yourdomain_baseurl/admin/post_action/id/action
```

in your 'admin' controller, you can create something like this:

```
function post_action($id, $action){

    switch ($action) {
        case "delete":
            //do something here with your post with id $id
            break;
        case "update":
            //do something here with your post with id $id
            break;
        case "create":
            //do something here with your post with id $id
            break;
    }

}
```

Or if you like to create a seperate function for each Post action:

```
http://yourdomain_baseurl/admin/post_delete/id
http://yourdomain_baseurl/admin/post_edit/id
```

With the following functions in your admin controller

```
function post_delete($id){
    //Delete Archive the post with $id here!
}

function post_edit($id){
    //edit the post with $id here!
}
```

As most user input comes from forms, you can use $_POST data get user input. There is a usefull class to help you out:

```
 $this->input->post('some_data');
```

I suggest reading the documentation that comes with codeigniter and read the following:

URL's
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

URls
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html